# How to go from a managed object context to a table view row?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableView`, using a CoreData SQLLite data source and `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Forgive me if I do not get this terminology correct, because I've only been at this for a few days now, so I'm just learning.

I just finished setting up a modal view to let me add new items to my data source. So, my logic right now is basically: add item to data source, refresh table view, I can now see my new item listed.

I want to take it a step farther, though, and perform a segue that I have setup that then occurs when the `UITableViewCell` for that any item is clicked. So I'm going to initiate that segue in code, using the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` method. The sender has to be the `UITableViewCell`, though.

So, given the things I have, I have the data that I just added to my data source, but do not know the index of the new item in the data source. I need to use that data to locate the `UITableViewCell` for the newly created item.

Any ideas on how to do this? I've been looking around and I have not seen any example code that looks like what I'm expecting to see.

Below is my code for adding the new item, from my modal view, to the data source:

```
#pragma mark - ComposeThreadViewControllerDelegate Methods

- (void)composeThreadViewController:(ComposeThreadViewController *)controller didFinishComposing:(Thread *)thread {

    // get the context
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    // add this new thread to our local cache
    NSManagedObject *managedThread = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Thread" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [managedThread setValue:thread.id forKey:@"id"];
    [managedThread setValue:thread.title forKey:@"title"];
    [managedThread setValue:thread.author forKey:@"author"];
    [managedThread setValue:thread.text forKey:@"text"];
    [managedThread setValue:thread.location forKey:@"location"];

    //save the new thread
    [context save:nil];

    // begin refreshing the list of threads
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // dismiss the modal view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // bring up the view item view
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewThreadSegue" sender:self];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the index path of the object?  That is an implementation detail of the table view, which is managing the presentation of your objects.

If you need the object, why not just pass the managed object as the sender?

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewThreadSegue" sender:managedThread];
```

Now, in your performSeque, you can pass the managed object to the view controller.  No need to pollute all of your code with index paths that are unnatural to what you are doing.

NOTE: you can ask the object for its managed object context...

```
managedThread.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: that is a good idea. i'll have to add some logic to my `prepareForSegue` method to see what the sender is, since it can also be a `UITableViewCell`, etc. i'll have to try this out in the morning.

Comment: Will it possibly be a cell when the identifier is "viewThreadSeque" or is it a cell for a different seque.  In any event, you could use the identifier, isKindOfClass, or just give the object to the controller and let the controller figure out what to do with it... or severla other methods

Comment: could be a cell, if they tap one themselves. i manually do the same thing as tapping a cell after a new item has been created, too. so in my manual scenario is when it'll be the thread that i already have. in the event that they tap a pre-existing item, it'll be a cell.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know studying cocoa for Mac OS X, you don't need to implement the data source protocol.You can just drag an array controller to interface builder, in the identity inspector set the mode to entity name, and type the name of the data source entity that you have created.After this you just have to bind each column of the table view to the array controller's key that you want to represent.

Comment: Sorry, your experiences in OS X does not fit in. Neither NSArrayController is available to iOS, nor the binding in Xib/Interface Builder.